# How to open database to see values when exported from DDMS?

Tags: android, database

I have a app that has a database... So through DDMS i exported its database as `.db` so i want to know how do I open it to see its tables/values ? Is there a specific program that opens it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any SQLite software, for example, [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) or [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index). If you use FireFox, you can use [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).

Comment: Alright, i do use Firefox(sometimes) i will check, by the way does Chrome have it aswell or only Firefox?

Comment: As far as I know, only FireFox.

Comment: Ahmm ok, so i download and installed in firefox, so now how do i open it ? (i have my database.db in my desktop.)

Comment: Just start the SQLite Manager from the FireFox menu (for me it's in the Web Developer submenu).

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have SSH-access to your rooted android device, you can use sqlite3 program from console and perform any SQL queries you want. By such way you do not need to copy database from device, and can debug what you need in real time.